# Angular 15 + CDK - ComponentPortal: Method argument to call components dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cdk

#### Problem description

In app.component.ts I'm instantiate ComponentPortal and try to pass different component names as arguments (but only one at time). So for example instead of the following, "hard coded" Component "PopupComponent"

#### component file (ts)

```
...
const popupComponentPortal = new ComponentPortal(PopupComponent);
...
```

I would like to pass dynamically arguments from the method call.

```
...
const popupComponentPortal = new ComponentPortal(selectedComponent);
...
```

**selectedComponent**: Which can be either PopupComponent, RedComponent or BlueComponent.

#### template file (html)

desired method call from template file:

```
...
<button class="button" (click)="openPopup(anchorPoint, 'RedComponent')">
  Open popup red
</button>

<button class="button" (click)="openPopup(anchorPoint, 'BlueComponent')">
  Open popup blue
</button>
...
```

How can I dynamically pass arguments?

#### StackBlitz Sample:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/overlay-flexible-connected-1h8hv4?file=src/app/app.module.ts

I tried to pass the component name as string in the method call in the template file but failed because I wasn't able to cast later the string to a Component Type.

I expect a simple but dynamically way to pass arguments for different components in the method ComponentPortal.

Is there a way to achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this arrives late but you can use an object or a map to handle this case. Also keep in mind adding the components that are you going to use to your NgModule. If I could give you an advice on Modules, try starting implementing `standalone modules`, since it will be the [new standard](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components) for angular.

This is the stackblitz with the modified solution.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/overlay-flexible-connected-foqfzv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts